# Publish NPM package that uses a workspaces as dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

so I have a project that I'm working on that is a Monorepo. So I have a `packages` directory in the root directory that contains all my npm packages. Some of these packages rely on eachother e.g. in a package.json I might have

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "workspace:*",
        "bar": "workspace:*",
    }
}
```

(I use pnpm)

So I was wondering, if I were to post these packages, would all the dependencies still work the way they should?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pnpm will do all the work for you when using `pnpm publish` (instead of `npm publish`).

It will automatically replace this:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "workspace:*",
        "bar": "workspace:*",
    }
}
```

with the current version, for example:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "1.5.0",
        "bar": "1.5.0",
    }
}
```

cf https://pnpm.io/workspaces#publishing-workspace-packages

Comment: Is there an equivalent feature in npm?