# Using lerna to publish packages that use yarn workspaces

Tags: versioning, monorepo, lerna, yarn-workspaces

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049086/publish-npm-package-that-uses-a-workspaces-as-dependencies) but using `lerna publish` and yarn workspaces instead of `pnpm publish`...

1. Publishing five packages in a monorepo
2. Using lerna fixed/locked mode for versioning.
3. Version to be produced is `2.0.0`.
4. Assume yarn workspaces and the lerna.json are setup correctly.
5. Four of those packages are dependent on a package in the monorepo called `foo`. Each of those four packages have a yarn workspace dependency like this...

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "workspace:*"
    }
}
```

When I perform a `lerna publish`, will it automatically replace `workspace:*` in the four packages with `2.0.0`? I didn't see this explicitly stated with regard to yarn workspaces on https://lerna.js.org/docs/features/version-and-publish. I assume it would be similar to pnpm but thought I'd check just in case.

Comment: there shouldn't be any differences with pnpm and yarn output, at least I think. On the other hand [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite), that I maintain, offers a `--dry-run` flag which is helpful to see exactly what gets produced, I think Lerna will add such flag in their future major version

Comment: That is a feature coming to lerna 7 that would answer this definitively!